# Findbug windows batch commands using maven in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, findbugs

I am trying to find bugs in a java file. I have added findbug plugin that is integrated with maven in Jenkins. I have used the following commands:

```
mvn compile
mvn findbugs:findbugs
```

I have a confusion on where to locate a file in the above command(.ear or .java file etc) for finding bugs.

Comment: It runs findbugs on your project in the current directory.

Comment: I have installed apache maven 2.2.1 version and added the maven name and path in Jenkins-Global Tool Configuration.                                                                                                 ' call mvn clean . It is throwing error like
    'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.'